# Using Google docs API in local intranet

Tags: php, google-docs-api, intranet

Is any way to use Google docs API in offline (local intranet)?
I need to open Excel file in browser like Google docs.

Thanks.

P.S. Language of programming - PHP

Comment: No.  Google does not provide distributions of the Google Docs service (or compatible).

Comment: You can however use any of the numerous web office suits which include a spreadsheet module: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_office_suites#Online_office_suites